# Feature Inquiry: Recommending a Change to the Author, not Peer Review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

After a point contributors with enough reputation can modify a question through peer review (or even directly).

However is it possible to recommend the change directly to the author and wait for their own response without overriding their version when the author is an active site user?

Comment: I think that is a constructive use of the [comment facility](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and in fact, how comments are often used with Qs on BH.SE. Direct editing should be done, though, when it's a matter of correcting a mistake; it's a different matter when suggesting an improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. And this is by design.

[The SE system](http://stackexchange.com/) is designed around the concept of peer review, collaborative editing, and the community being the ultimate judge of useful vs. not useful content. This is a paradigm shift that takes some getting used to, but the concept is worth striving towards. Adding features that encourage the opposite would not be good for the sites in the network.

A feature that suggests edits without actually implementing them would only foster the misconception that the content is owned by the author rather than by the community. This is not a blogging platform nor a forum where people should expect to maintain a high degree of control over the content they write. On SE sites the content is *contributed* to the community and licensed under a Creative Commons license that gives the community the freedom to extend and modify it as they see fit. The current tooling around the post edit system is designed to encourage this, not to stifle it.

The help system gives a pretty detailed description of the [editing system](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/editing) that includes this:

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Encouraging direct edits to be reviewed by the whole community rather than leaving it to the whims of the original author is one of the reasons the overall quality of content on SE sites tends to be higher than free-for-all forums.

Comment: And on that note, I just edited this post without Caleb's approval ;)